# Remove commas after javascript push function in object

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object that contains

```
[ 'My', 'name', 'is', 'John' ]
```

However, when i print out the complete object it prints out with commas on my html page. How can i remove the commas in the object list?
My page only allows to render an object which mean i cant convert to a string and do it from there.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: it looks like an array rather than an object, if so then you can use [`.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).  Can you edit your question to show us the code that produes / uses it

Answer (score 1):

Use .join() instead of .toString()

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
`[ 'My', 'name', 'is', 'John' ].join(' ');`

Answer (score 0):

Run a join on it and then convert it back to an array object?

```
console.log(new Array([ 'My', 'name', 'is', 'John' ].join(' ')));
// -> Array: ["My name is John"]
```

This converts it back to a JavaScript array object but with a single value equal to all of the previous individual values concatenated.